# Cordova | CodePush is it still working?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, ionic3, code-push

Cordova | CodePush is it still working?
CrossWalk is deprecated, someone said to me.

so is it still supported / working?

have been trying everything on net on the last 2 days but can't make it work.
working with android | ionic 2/3 | and tried also pure cordova.

thanks

Comment: Why should Crosswalk be deprecated?

Comment: i dont know.some ionic software guy told me that.
is it true?

i also found the :
https://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/

but it doesnt work for me. it is unclear where exactly should i put the client code, id...